# Why does the vector field $(\sin (\theta), - \cos(\theta), 0)$ indicate sideways motion?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, physics, vector-analysis, parametric

If I study a physical system, such as a car, and let it drive forward a little bit, say a distance $m$,  then I can draw out the right triangle and find the car's position at $(m\cos \theta, m\sin\theta, 0)$.  But why is the car's total displacement, exactly sideways after parallel parking, given by the vector field $(\sin\theta, - \cos\theta, 0)$?

I can't seem to see this.  My guess is that I have some basic high school math that I just have to brush up on, but I've been trying for awhile now and thought I'd ask the question on this forum at this point.

Thanks,

Comment: [This tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) may help you to make your math formulas easier to read, which will help people answer your question. It will also help to give a little more information about the problem: does the car start at the origin $(0,0)$ and drive along a straight line at angle $\theta$ to the $x$-axis (as your description suggests)? When parallel parking, is there any further description of what is happening (where the car starts, where it ends up)? You can edit these details directly into the question.

Comment: From the formulas, I guess that "parallel parking" means the car starts at $(0,0)$ pointing along the line at angle $\theta$ to the $x$-axis, and the "parking" operation results in shifting the car $1$ unit toward its own right side. If that's correct, the formulas can be explained.

Comment: Hi @DavidK, I am thinking of the car driving not necessarily along the x-axis.  Say it drives forward (straight, without turning the steering wheel) a distance of m units, then this straight line, originating from (0,0), is the hypotenuse of a right triangle, and the car's position is now at (mcosθ,msinθ,0).  Yes, I believe that parallel parking means the cars starts at (0,0) also.  So, based on this information, does this vector field (sinθ,−cosθ,0) indicate sideways motion?  Thanks,

Comment: "At angle $\theta$ to the $x$-axis" means the car is _not_ going along the $x$-axis but instead is in a different direction in the $x,y$-plane (unless $\theta=0$). I think this agrees with the hypotenuse of your right triangle. If "straight ahead" goes from $(0,0,0)$ to $(m\cos\theta,m\sin\theta,0)$ then a vector in the direction $90$ degrees to the right of that has coordinates $(\sin\theta,-\cos\theta,0)$. So yes, that vector does indicate sideways motion relative to the "forward" line. It sounds like you have the idea.

Comment: Hi @DavidK, I understand the vector field that indicates the "forward" driving motion, (mcosθ,msinθ,0), but I actually don't understand how the vector field that indicates the sideways displacement (after the car has been parallel parked) is derived.  How do we arrive at (sinθ,−cosθ,0)?  I think I'm having an issue recalling some basic pre-calculus / plane geometry that was covered way back in high school...but I can't seem to figure out what it is that I am forgetting.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just have to draw a picture. Based on the question, with some
reinforcement in its comments, I hope this is the correct picture of what is wanted:

[image]

So the car's direction of forward travel would be in the direction
of the longer vector (of length $m$)
while the end result of "parallel parking" would be to move the car in the direction
of the shorter vector, that is, $1$ unit distance in a direction perpendicular to
the forward path and on the right side of that path.

Following the convention that angles are measured counterclockwise,
and given an angle $\theta$ between the longer vector and the $x$-axis,
the coordinates of the car after moving forward a distance $m$
(that is the longer vector)
would be $(m \cos \theta, m \sin \theta)$.

There are a couple of ways to find the coordinates at the end of the
parallel parking maneuver.
By geometry, we can construct a right triangle 
with hypotenuse $m$ along the longer vector, one leg along the $x$-axis
and angle $\theta$ between those two sides;
the sides of this triangle are $m \cos \theta, m \sin \theta, m$.
There is also a triangle with hypotenuse $1$ along the shorter vector and a leg
along the $y$-axis, with angle $\theta$ between those two sides;
this triangle is proportional to the first triangle and has sides
$\cos \theta, \sin \theta, 1$.
By inspection we can see that the $x$ coordinate at the end of the forward motion
corresponds to the negative $y$ coordinate at the end of the parking motion,
whereas the $y$ coordinate after forward motion corresponds to the $x$
coordinate after parking;
that is, parking takes the car to $(\sin \theta, -\cos \theta).$

Alternatively, we can see that the second vector is in a direction at
an angle $\frac\pi2$ ($90$ degrees) clockwise from the first vector, 
which means (by the counterclockwise convention) that it is at an angle
$\theta - \frac\pi2$ relative to the $x$-axis.
For the same reason the first vector takes the car to $(m \cos \theta, m \sin \theta)$,
the second vector should take it to 
$\left(\cos\left(\theta - \frac\pi2\right), \sin\left(\theta - \frac\pi2\right)\right)$.
But from trigonometry we know that

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\cos\left(\theta - \frac\pi2\right)
 &=& \cos\theta \, \cos\frac\pi2 + \sin\theta \, \sin\frac\pi2 \\
 &=& \cos\theta \cdot 0 + \sin\theta \cdot 1 \\
 &=& \sin\theta
\end{eqnarray}$$
and
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\sin\left(\theta - \frac\pi2\right)
 &=& \sin\theta \, \cos\frac\pi2 - \cos\theta \, \sin\frac\pi2 \\
 &=& \sin\theta \cdot 0 - \cos\theta \cdot 1 \\
 &=& -\cos\theta.
\end{eqnarray}$$

So the coordinates actually come to $(\sin \theta, -\cos \theta).$
Since these trigonometric identities are valid at any angle, we do not have to
do any extra work to confirm this formula works for forward directions into
the other three quadrants, not just in the first quadrant as shown.

A third approach is to obtain the second vector by setting $m=1$ 
(so the first vector is unit length)
and rotating the first vector through an angle $-\frac\pi2$ ($90$ degrees clockwise)
using a rotation matrix, which again will come to the same result.